# listToArray Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

**The book says:**

To run over a list (in listToArray and nth), a for loop specification like this can be used:

```
for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {}
```

Every iteration of the loop, node points to the current sublist, and the body can read its value property to get the current element. At the end of an iteration, node moves to the next sublist. When that is null, we have reached the end of the list and the loop is finished.

**Question 1**: Could you explain how the condition of the for loop works? I understand that it is checking whether the node(the current list) is null.. but how does the "node" argument by itself work?

**Question 2**: why doesnt the following code work?

```
function listToArray(list){
    var result = [];
    while(list.value != null){
        result.push(list.value);
        list = list.rest;
    }
    return result;
};

console.log(listToArray(list));
```

Comment: For what it's worth in modern JavaScript you'd make the list iterable rather than rolling your own iteration scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand how this works, you need to know two things:

- How java script [**For**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop works.
- What are [**truthy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values.

The `syntax` for the for loop statement:

> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])    statement
>
> [condition] An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration.
>   If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. If the
>   expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression
>   following the for construct.

In Java script, a `truthy` value evaluates to true when evaluated in a Boolean context.

> All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except
>   for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

So till `node` is `null` at one point, we *[may](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)* say that `node` is `truthy` and evaluates to true.

When the statement, `node = node.rest` assigns a `null` value to `node`, there the for loop exits.

The below code does not work because, `list.value` may be `undefined`, or as a fact any other `falsy` value other than `null`.

```
function listToArray(list){
    var result = [];
    while(list.value != null){
        result.push(list.value);
        list = list.rest;
    }
    return result;
};

console.log(listToArray(list));
```

instead try, `while(list.value)`.

Answer (score 2):

> ...but how does the "node" argument by itself work?

`node` is a **variable**. A variable is resolved to its value. E.g. if I have

```
var foo = 3;
alert(foo + 1);
```

it will resolve `foo` to the value `3` and then add `1` to it. Similarly in this case, `node` is resolved to whatever value it has, that value is *converted to a Boolean value* (i.e. `Boolean(node)`) and then tested whether it is `true` or `false`.

If the value of `node` is `null`, then `Boolean(node)` will return `false`.

> why doesnt the following code work?

Can't really tell without knowing what `list` is and what exactly "does not work".

But presumably, `list.rest` is `null` at some point, in which case you would try to access `null.value` which throws an error. The equivalent version to the `for` loop would be to compare `list` itself:

```
while (list != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use:
var result = Array.prototype.slice.call(list);

this will turn the list into an array

Answer (score 0):

```
function listToArray(listValue){
     var arrayResult = [];

     while(listValue.list){
        arrayResult.push(listValue.value);
        listValue = listValue.list;
      }

    arrayResult.push(listValue.value);

    return arrayResult;
}
```