# What is the meaning of these codes? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

```
function arrayToList(array) {
    let list = [];
    for(let element of array) {
        list = {value: element, rest: list};
    }
    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([1, 2, 3]));
// -> {value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: [] } }}
```

In this code,what does this line? Can you describe?
**list = {value: element, rest: list};**

```
function listToArray(list) {
    let array = [];
    for(let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
        array.push(node.value);
    }
    return array;
}

console.log({value: 1, rest: { value: 3, rest: [] }});
// -> [1, 3];
```

In this code, how does this line works?
**for(let node = list; node; node = node.rest) { expression }**

Comment: Oh, the `[]` threw me off for a moment. You're creating a linked list, and are returning the last object in the list, though I don't think the result in your comment is accurate. The numbers look reversed.

Comment: I want to point out that in fact your output for the first example is wrong. It's `{value: 3, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 1, rest: [] } }}`, not `{value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: [] } }}`. And the second example output, assuming you meant to pass it to `listToArray()`, is `[1, 3, undefined]`, not `[1, 3]`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts , sorry. You are right, just a wrong output, thanks :)

Comment: @doodlemeister , thanks for answer. Can you help step by step please? Because i can't understand, i'm confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800442/eloquent-javascript-chapter-4-arraytolist-listtoarray-execise and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224512/listtoarray-eloquent-javascript

Comment: @Bergi , thanks too much! That is a good answer for first question, thanks so much :) How can I up vote you?

Comment: @n3pixowe Just vote on the answers there :-)

Comment: @Bergi, I can't see anything overhere for up vote. Which button i must to press and where is it ?

Comment: @n3pixowe Nothing here, you can just vote on my comment. Over there, vote on the answer by clicking the up arrow.

Comment: @Bergi i can't, i need 15 populations. Anway, thanks so much. I will close this ask but i cant select your answer for solution.

Comment: @n3pixowe Oh, right. You don't need to do anything, the question is already closed.

Comment: @Bergi Ok thanks so much again :)

Answer (score 1):

It recursively nests the values of an array inside an object. The second function de-nests them back out to an array.

It reminds me of a linked list. Though I can't imagine why this would be useful in a language like JavaScript which effectively lacks pointers.

Comment: Yes, I have. The second function de-nests them back out to an array.

Comment: Oh sorry, I can't believe I missed that. ;_;. Don't mind what I say... Have an upvote!

Comment: John Ellmore, thanks for answer. Can you help step by step? I'm confused af.

Comment: "Reminds you"? It *is* a linked list. And while JS doesn't have pointers, object references are by far enough for that.